# How to store an array of String as an enumeration type

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, readfile

I have made two classes, one is called Card, and the other is Pack.
The Card class has the following attributes :

```
private String Name;
private int Magic;
private int Cunning;
private int Courage;
private int Wisdom;
private int Temper;
```

In the Pack class, I have made a file reader methods that read a file on my PC and store each line of it as a string array. So for example this is a part of the text (not code):

```
 Pansy_Parkinson
 42
 21
 18
 19
 9
 Dean_Thomas
 40
 10
 35
 22
 4
```

My String array[] stores each line as a different index.
**What I want to do**, is to convert this String array to array of type Card.
It should store in each index a card with the 6 attributes..

So I suppose I will need to have a method to convert it, and I will have my new 2D Card array based on the previous text this way:

```
Card [][] ArrayOfCards = new Card [1][5];
```

Please, any idea how I can do this?

..........................................................
..........................................................

Thank you very much everyone for your valuable helps!
I tried all codes and they seemed great! but I don't know why it's showing me errors either in my main or the methods themselves..

Here is my FileReader class!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.*; //To deal with exceptions
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadFile {

        private Scanner x;
        private String Path;

        public ReadFile (String ThePath){
            Path = ThePath;
        }

        public String[] openFile() throws IOException /*To throw any errors up the line*/
        {
            FileReader FR = new FileReader(Path);
            BufferedReader TextReader = new BufferedReader(FR);

            int NoOfLines = readLines();
            String[] TextData = new String[NoOfLines];

            for (int i = 0; i < NoOfLines; i++)
                TextData[i] = TextReader.readLine(); //Accesses the lines of text and stores them in the array

            TextReader.close();
            return TextData;
        }

        int readLines() throws IOException //Return the number of lines in the text
        {
            FileReader FR2 = new FileReader(Path);
            BufferedReader BF = new BufferedReader(FR2);

            String ALine;
            int NoOfLines = 0;

            while ((ALine = BF.readLine()) != null)//Read each line of text & stop when a null value's reached
            NoOfLines++;

            BF.close();
            return NoOfLines;
        }

}
```

And I have just read it yet on main as like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        String FileName = "C:/Users/Anwar/Desktop/Potter.txt"; //Path of the file on my PC
        try {
            ReadFile File = new ReadFile(FileName); 
            String[] ArrayLines = File.openFile();
            for(int i = 0; i < ArrayLines.length; i++) 
                System.out.println(ArrayLines[i]);
            }
        catch (IOException e) /*Defiend object of type IOException*/ {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }}
```

Anyone can help me in this?

Comment: `Card[] ArrayOfCards` should be enough. why it has to be 2D? or probably `List<Card>` will be even better

Comment: Personally I'd create a static `Parse` method on the `Card` class that takes a `string` and returns a `Card` or throws an exception if the `string` is not formatted correctly.  Then you just need to fed the strings that represent a `Card` into it.  Also I'd recommend using lists instead of arrays.  And I think you have Pansy Parkinson's Temper way too low.

Comment: why not using serialization methods?

Comment: I agree with @ASh. Also, you have a Java and a c# tag in your question. Which language are you using?

Comment: @DarrenGourley I'm guessing Java. `someType[][]` is how multidimensional arrays are defined, where as in C# it's `someType[,]`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a c# tag with your question I decided to give a c# example, which you should be able to convert over to java fairly easily.

Essentially I've created a `Card` class which has a constructor that accepts the 6 stats about the card. I've kept the fields `private` as this is how they are in your Question.
I've create a `for` loop that runs through each of the items in the array, effectively taking 6 items at a time and passing them through to the `Card` constructor. We're then adding this `card` to our `List` of `Cards`.

I also threw in a quick `ToInt()` extension to tidy up the `Card` instantiation.

There are going to be better ways of doing this, but this solves the problem you have presented us with. There is also no error handling in this example.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rawData = new string[]{
                 "Pansy_Parkinson",
                 "42",
                 "21",
                 "18",
                 "19",
                 "9",
                 "Dean_Thomas",
                 "40",
                 "10",
                 "35",
                 "22",
                 "4"
            };

            var Cards = new List<Card>();

            for(int i = 0; i < rawData.Length; i+=6)
            {
                var card = new Card(rawData[0 + i], rawData[1 + i].ToInt(), rawData[2 + i].ToInt(), rawData[3 + i].ToInt(), rawData[4 + i].ToInt(), rawData[5 + i].ToInt());
                Cards.Add(card);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static int ToInt(this string item)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(item);
        }
    }

    public class Card
    {
        private string Name;
        private int Magic;
        private int Cunning;
        private int Courage;
        private int Wisdom;
        private int Temper;

        public Card(string name, int magic, int cunning, int courage, int wisdom, int temper)
        {
            Name = name;
            Magic = magic;
            Cunning = cunning;
            Courage = courage;
            Wisdom = wisdom;
            Temper = temper;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to od it like that:

Create constructor for Card with param String array[][] and which will be the array created from text file and second param which will be the int number that will say where to search for the data for constructor

the constructor should work like this:

```
Card(String[][] array, int numberForConstructor){

this.name = array[numberForConstructor][0];
this.magic = array[numberForConstructor][1];
this.cunning = array[numberForConstructor][2];
this.courage = array[numberForConstructor][3];
this.temper = array[numberForConstructor][4];
}
```

then you can use this constructor to put new Card objects to Array, List or anything you want

Answer (score 0):

You should create getter/setter for your class Card, then you can use this function. I don't know which language you use (c# or java) so you will have to adjust the solution bellow.

```
public class Pack
{
    public List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();

    public Pack(string filename)
    {
        // Your parsing function
        while ((line = readLine() != null)
        {
            Card c = new Card();
            c.setName(line);
            c.setMagic(Convert.ToInt32(readLine());
            c.setCunning(Convert.ToInt32(readLine());
            c.setCourage(Convert.ToInt32(readLine());
            c.setWisdom(Convert.ToInt32(readLine());
            c.setTemper(Convert.ToInt32(readLine());
            cards.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you to create a new Pack just do the following

```
Pack p = new Pack("cards.txt");
p.cards[0].getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams that your input array has one card parameter per line. So I think you are simply looking for something like this:

```
public static Card[] convert(String[] arr){
    if(arr.length % 6 != 0){
        System.out.println("error in data");
        return null;
    }
    Card[] res = new Card[arr.length / 6];

    for(int i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
        String Name = arr[(i * 6) + 0];
        int Magic = Integer.parseInt(arr[(i * 6) + 1]);
        int Cunning  = Integer.parseInt(arr[(i * 6) + 2]);
        int Courage = Integer.parseInt(arr[(i * 6) + 3]);
        int Wisdom = Integer.parseInt(arr[(i * 6) + 4]);
        int Temper = Integer.parseInt(arr[(i * 6) + 5]);
        res[i] = new Card(Name, Magic, Cunning, Courage, Wisdom, Temper);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This can work:**

```
public Card ConvertArrayToCard(string[] array)
{
       Card card = new Card;
       card.Name = array[0];
       card.Magic= array[1];
       card.Cunning= array[2];
       card.Courage= array[3];
       card.Wisdom= array[4];
       card.Temper= array[5];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few answers.. Here is another one.

Your class;

```
public class Pack
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Magic { get; set; }
   public int Cunning { get; set; }
   public int Courage { get; set; }
   public int Wisdom { get; set; }
   public int Temper { get; set; }
}
```

Then the logic. There is some built in defensive coding mechanism in this. I will let you figure that out.

```
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp2.txt");
            List<Pack> mypack =  new List<Pack>();
            Pack member = null;
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                int val;
                count = (!int.TryParse(line, out val)) ? 0 : count + 1;
                switch (count)
                {
                    case 0:
                        member = new Pack() { Name = line.Trim() };
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        member.Magic = val;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        member.Cunning = val;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        member.Courage = val;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        member.Wisdom = val;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        member.Temper = val;
                        mypack.Add(member);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return mypack;
```